# Getting this error: "error "oversized data"

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment

When I am trying to deploy my smart contract(It is a 600+ lines smart contract)through truffle framework (version 4.1.14)  on Rinkeby testnet it is showing the above error.But when I am deploying the same contract with remix ide and using metal mask then it is deployed successfully. I know that the code size limit of 32KB is in ethereum-go implementation to avoid DOS attack.So if anyone can answer why the contract is getting deployed with remix but not with truffle.
Here is the link on rinkbey testnet
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xe42b8fa9a7aab732a633465a84e8a56433eb482e0cb5aa49ed38f5428dfc82a4

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be that you have optimisation turned on in remix, but not in Truffle. This would mean that under remix the code size is small enough to deploy, but not under Truffle.

You can add something like:

  `solc: {
    optimizer: {
      enabled: true,
      runs: 200,
    },
  }`

to truffle.js to turn on optimisation. There is switch under settings in remix that does the same thing.

Comment: I enabled the optimizer but the error is still the same. “error ”oversized data".

Comment: I'd need to see the code then to try and work out what was going on.

Comment: Sorry . I cannot post the smart contract codes .company policies. Now I am changing the  ethereum-go implementation codes. Increasing the tx.Size value to 128Kb. Here is the question related to this I asked.https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/59778/is-it-safe-to-make-the-the-code-size-to-128kb-in-ethereum-private-networki-have

Comment: I have updated the tx.Size value to 128KB.For this, I cloned the official go-ethereum repository and then used make geth command.and after all this run two nodes and tried deploying the smart contract but still same error over sized data.Is  it because I wasn't able to use the geth implementaion correctly according to change in  tx_pool.go file?

Comment: Can you deploy to ganache? Ganache enforces the same 32Kb limit, but can be overriden using:  
`ganache-cli --allowUnlimitedContractSize`
So if it works with this flag, and doesn't work without the flag, you at least know it is def. related to this issue.

Comment: I tried using ganache with unlimited contractSize flag but now I am getting this
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas. Even when I am using the upper limit of allowed gas. Is it possible that there is no ether in wallet?But I don't think so because ganache already gives 100 ether to each account when it starts.

Comment: If you run ganache with:  `ganache-cli --allowUnlimitedContractSize --l 0xfffffffffff` and set the gaslimit in `truffle.js` to a high value (e.g. 20mm) you should be able to determine whether it is related to block gas limits or not. Otherwise I'd suggest sharing the repo with the truffle project you're trying to deploy.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this error was just to split the bigger smart contracts into smaller ones and use inheritance.